# Preferences datastore with dynamic name: Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>) method

Tags: android, android-jetpack-datastore

Why does getting a datastore work when using `val` but not when using `fun`?

```
val Context.settingsDataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

fun Context.test(name: String){
    // Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
    val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = name)
}
```

When clicking on the suggestion, the following code is generated:

```
private operator fun <T, V> ReadOnlyProperty<T, V>.getValue(v: V?, property: KProperty<V?>): V {

}
```

However, the `operator` has the following error: `'operator' modifier is inapplicable on this function: second parameter must be of type KProperty<*> or its supertype`.

---

Originally, I thought the context was passed through `this`, but it turns out that there is no `this` when using `val`.

```
val Context.example = this.getString(R.string.example) // Extension property cannot be initialized because it has no backing field

// correct way
val Context.example: String
    get() = this.getString(R.string.example)
```